# erlang: exception error when evaluating an arithmetic expression

Tags: erlang

```
-module(test2).
-export([main/1]).
calc(Cnt, Total) when Cnt > 0 ->
  calc(Cnt - 1, (Total + 2 * 34 + 1) / 2 * 39);
calc(0, Total)->
  io:format("~p ~n", [Total]),
  ok.
main([A])->
  Cnt = list_to_integer(A),
  calc(Cnt, 1).
```

It's weird executing above codes:

```
$ escript test2.beam 900000000
escript: exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
  in function  test2:calc/2 (test2.erl, line 4)
  in call from escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 752)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 276)
  in call from init:start_it/1 
  in call from init:start_em/1
```

If I remove the `* 39`, then everything is ok.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point overflow. The floating point division operator `/` turns your `Total` variable into a double-precision floating point number. After a certain number of iterations, the result of multiplying with 39 exceeds the maximum value this type can hold.

Comment: Then the integer is arbitrary size and never overflow, but the float is fixed size and would be overflow?